# Number of sequences of only ones and zeroes, where the number of zeroes is greater than the number of ones

Tags: combinatorics, induction

As part of an exercise I'm doing, I would like to use the following claim:

> The number of sequences with a length of $2n+1$ of zeroes and ones
>   only, the number of sequences whereas there are more zeroes than ones
>   is $ \frac{2^{2n+1}}{2}$

For some reason it looks pretty trivial, but I do not have a clue how to prove this claim.

I thought about using induction, but without any success.

Is this really a trivial clain, or is there a clever way of proving it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's trivial....just remark that ties are impossible and there is an equal chance that $H>T$ or $T>H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of sequences with a majority of $0$'s and $B$ the set of sequences with a majority of $1$'s. Define a function $f:A\rightarrow B$ that picks a sequence and exchanges all $0$'s for $1$'s and vice versa. That's a bijection. Therefore $|A| = |B|$. Since the number of items in the sequence is odd you can't have an equal number of $0$'s and $1$'s. Therefore all the sequences belong to either $A$ or $B$. Also note that $A\cap B = ø$. Finally we can write 
$$|A|+|B| = 2^{2n+1}$$
$$2|A| = 2^{2n+1}$$
$$|A| = \frac{2^{2n+1}}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

There are $2^{2n+1}$ sequences of $0$s and $1$s. Half of them are going to have more ones and zeros and half of them and going to have more zeros than ones. Hence $\frac{2^{2n+1}}{2}$ is your answer.

Comment: Thanks, but is this sufficent? no need to formally prove that?